# google recaptcha doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with google recaptcha. I have a file with form and file with just php validation. I can't get value of **g-recaptcha-response** and I really dont know why.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey = '6L***.....';
$something = file_get_contents($url."?secret=" . $privatekey . "&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data= json_decode($something);
if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success == true)
{
    echo "right";
} 
else {
    echo "failed bruh";
}
```

I have included JavaScript and also used the right key.

Comment: And what debugging have you done?

Comment: Everything you need can be found at: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

Comment: So i dont know why but when i put my that div under <form> tag it worked but when its before </form> tag its not working...